# How to stop esc from closing my fullscreen video in javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, escaping, keydown, fullscreenchange

Currently working on a **video player** that has a specific **styling class** added to it if the video is *fullscreen*. If user exits using **esc** and not fullscreen button, the styling stays put.

```js
/* View in fullscreen */
function openFullscreen(elem) {
  if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
    elem.requestFullscreen();
  } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) { /* Safari */
    elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
  } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) { /* IE11 */
    elem.msRequestFullscreen();
  }

  video.classList.add('video-fullscreen');
}

/* Close fullscreen */
function closeFullscreen() {
  if (document.exitFullscreen) {
    document.exitFullscreen();
  } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) { /* Safari */
    document.webkitExitFullscreen();
  } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) { /* IE11 */
    document.msExitFullscreen();
  }

  video.classList.remove('video-fullscreen');
}

let fullscreen = false;

//Toggle fullscreen
function toggleFullScreen(){
    !fullscreen ? openFullscreen(player) : closeFullscreen();
    fullscreen = !fullscreen;
}
```

I tried an **event listener** for the **esc** button so I could use it to **change the styling back**, the first esc press closes and second does my code, very annoying:

```js
//detect Escape key press
window.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
    if(e.key === "Escape" && fullscreen){
        e.preventDefault();
        closeFullscreen();
        fullscreen = !fullscreen;
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not try to intercept the escape keypress and derive implications for your fullscreen mode from that. Instead, you [should listen for `fullscreenchange` events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/requestFullScreen#Detecting_full-screen_activation) - which also won't fire if `requestFullscreen` fails:

> To learn when other code has toggled full-screen mode on and off, you
> should establish listeners for the [`fullscreenchange` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/fullscreenchange) on the
> `Document`. It's also important to listen for `fullscreenchange` to be
> aware when, for example, the user manually toggles full-screen mode,
> or when the user switches applications, causing your application to
> temporarily exit full-screen mode.

```
document.addEventListener('fullscreenchange', (event) => {
  video.classList.toggle('video-fullscreen', document.fullscreenElement != null);
});
```

However, you probably don't need this at all. Instead of the `.video-fullscreen` class, just use the [`:fullscreen` selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:fullscreen) in your CSS!

Comment: Ah, I hadn't encountered the :fullscreen pseudoclass yet, very helpful. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the removeClass method to your event listener callback function.

```
//detect Escape key press
window.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
    if(e.key === "Escape" && fullscreen){
        e.preventDefault();
        video.classList.remove('video-fullscreen');        
        closeFullscreen();
        fullscreen = !fullscreen;
   }
});
```